# Publishing a microservice in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I"m trying to push a microservice in a ECS Cluster in AWS, following this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/getting-started/projects/break-monolith-app-microservices-ecs-docker-ec2/module-one/

I clone the repository, login on AWS from AWS Cli, have run the commands, step by step:

[image]

[image]

Then i receive a message "no basic auth credentials".

Has Anybody faced this issue?

Comment: You might have authenticated for a different region? 
Or could it be that you are trying to push to a repository that you don't have permission to?
Look here for further debugging: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors-docker.html#error-403

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you haven't authenticated your Docker client to your registry.

To solve this, go to your ECR console in AWS. Then enter your repository. In there you should be able to find a button called **View push commands**. It will give you 
ready, copy-and-paste commands to authenticate, build, tag and push your image to ECR. The commands are for Linux, Mac and Windows.

The description of the commands for authentication is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth